# Could someone please tell me what the { _ in nil } does in this piece of Swift code

Tags: swift, dictionary

I know what will happen with the cos and the `{"cos(\($0))"}` parts but I don't understand what will happen with the `{_ in nil}` part.

```
enum Operation {
    case nullaryOperation(() -> Double, () -> String)
}

var operations: Dictionary<String,Operation> = [

    "cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cos, {"cos(\($0))"}, {_ in nil})

  ]

    func performOperation(_ symbol: String) {

        if let operation = operations[symbol] {

            switch operation {


            case .nullaryOperation(let function, let description):

                accumulator = (function(), description(), nil)
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide definition of unaryOperation instead of nullaryOperation

Comment: Read the language guide section on closures

Comment: `_ in nil` means "ignore whatever passed into this closure and always return `nil`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CodeDifferent mentioned `{_ in nil}` syntax means: ignore whatever passed into this closure and always return nil.
Consider this simple functions that gives a closure as input.

```
func myFunc(inputClosure: (arg: Int?) -> Int?){
    var num = inputClosure(arg: 2)
    print(num)
}
```

The output is equal to the input:

```
myFunc { (arg) -> Int? in
    return arg
}
```

No matter what the input is the output is 1000:

```
myFunc () { _ -> Int? in
    return 1000
}
```

no matter what the input is the output is nil:

```
// These are the same:

myFunc { (arg) -> Int? in nil
}

myFunc { _ -> Int? in nil
}
```